# setting SPField values for SPListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Rather than iterate through all the fields in an SPListItem SPFieldsCollection and rendering an input control for each one then trying to programmatically match them back up on post back.  Is there an inbuilt method of doing this? i.e. of reusing the same control in the edititem.aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListFieldIterator control does what you want . Refer to this [Link](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/listfielditerator/) for more details and Another [link](http://the-e.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=24).

Comment: thanks - I had found the answer before but couldnt for the life of me remember the name of the control.